# Modifying Regex to Exclude "END;" After "CASE" with Possible Text in Between

Tags: javascript, sql, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation

I have a regex pattern to find occurrences of "END;" in a text, but I need to modify it to exclude instances where "END;" appears after a "CASE" statement, even if there are line breaks or any other text in between them. Additionally, I want to ignore all occurrences of "END;" after the first one following a "CASE". Here's the existing regex pattern:

`const rightPattern = '\\bEND\\s*;';` 
How can I adjust this regex to meet the criteria mentioned above, considering the possibility of line breaks or any other text between "CASE" and "END"? Any help is appreciated!

Example input text:

-- Example with END; after CASE
CASE
WHEN condition1 THEN END; -- Exclude this END;

-- Another instance of END; not following CASE
END;

-- Example with line breaks and text between CASE and END;
CASE
WHEN condition2 THEN
someText
END; -- Exclude this END;

-- Example with text between CASE and END;
CASE
WHEN condition3 THEN someText END; -- Exclude this END;

I tried for example something like this: (?<!\bCASE.*)\bEND;
But this doesn't support line breaks, and looks only at the first occurence.

Comment: `(?<!\bCASE.*)\bEND` won't work even if breaks. `(?<!\bCASE[\S\s]*)\bEND`

Comment: If you're looking for unmatched, stray _`END`_ you'd need recursion. Balanced text or counting C#, (or JS?) There is a way to simulate this but I don't think it works under JS

Comment: Just FYI, Regex is not suitable for such complex requirements, it just isn't capable of what is in general known as "parsing". Programming languages (including SQL) are more complex than the simple "regular language" category for which Regular Expressions were created. You may succeed for certain limited, simple statements, but it will almost certainly break again when feeding it a new slightly more complex statement.

Comment: Here this regex sim works in most languages that don't do balanced or counters. 
`(?:(?=\bCASE)(?:(?=.*?\bCASE(?!.*?\1)(.*\bEND(?!.*\2).*))(?=.*?\bEND(?!.*?\2)(.*)).)+?.*?(?=\1)(?:(?!\bCASE).)*(?=\2$))*(?:(?!\bCASE).)*?\b(END)`

https://regex101.com/r/J27gvh/1
https://regex101.com/r/4nzNvt/1
https://regex101.com/r/KXyvE7/1
https://regex101.com/r/KxnVX4/1 If you're stuck with JS,  let me know and I'll supply you with a simple code balance routine.

Comment: @PeterB Can you state the complexity please ?

Comment: Your examples would be clearer if you separated the text from instructions of what you want to do with it. Consider putting the actual text on on line, then on the next line underline strings you want changed, then on the following line describe the desired change.

Comment: One approach is to match `\bCASE\b.*?\bEND\b|\b(END)\b` with the "single-line" or "DOTALL" flag set, so that periods in the regex will match all characters, including line terminators. `"END"s` that terminate CASE statements are parts of strings that are matched but not captured, whereas other `"END"s` are captured (to group 1) as well as matched. Therefore only pay attention to matches that are captured. Alternatively, match `\bCASE\b.*?\bEND\b|\bEND\b` and discard matches that are strings `"CASE...END"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks, the stirng that I need is "END;" and to not match END without the semicolon.
for some reason when I change to END; your solution doesn't work. not sure why.
https://regex101.com/r/BUMBeL/1

Comment: Lisa, the problem is `\b` here: `(END;)\b`. You need to remove it. Recall `\b` requires the next character to be a non-word character if the preceding character is a word character, but it also requires the next character to be a word character if the preceding character (here the semicolon) is a non-word character. In your example at the link `'END;'` is followed by a newline so it doesn't match. Note the word boundary is appropriate for `(END)\b`.